# Chrome doesn't load webapp on NodeJS

Tags: node.js, google-chrome

After yet another reboot of my macbook, chrome stopped loading my webapp.

It returns literally nothing in browser window and the only thing i managed to find is that requests in chrome's timeline has status "cancelled".
If I'm trying to get there from another website (by changin url and hitting "return" button), it also does nothing, it doesn't even try to reload page.

Other browsers load it fine atm.

I've received this report from a user about couple of weeks ago, but now i've got it myself, so I assume the problem is in my server.

Recently, i've found that my android phone also can't access the website from chrome browser. The behaviour is the same. However, android default browser has access.

What could that be? Where should i look?
I'd provide more information, but there is no error codes or messages of any kind, so i have no idea what information could help in this question.

Also, i have a chrom browser extension (similar to Pocket), which also is unable to access server. The notable difference is that extension uses Socket.io only.

There were no recent code changes on server side except [letsencrypt](https://github.com/Daplie/letsencrypt-cli) certificate renewal.

I've tried this:

- server restart
- different ip/locations (vpn and public access points)
- chrome data cleanup / chrome version degrade / chrome reinstallation / chrome canary installation
- tried to open server address directly - no difference

Comment: Can you provide any other information. If its on a live site where we can reproduce this?

Comment: What about your logs?

Comment: `pm2 logs` shows nothing upon chrome request

Comment: FYI, Opera doesn't load either so this definitely looks like a Chromium specific issue.

Comment: @Vercoutere, i doubt. I've just installed [yandex browser](https://browser.yandex.com/desktop/zen/), which is totally chromium-based chrome-replica, and it works fine. In fact, this browser even has got into my google profile, installed all of the extensions i have in chrome etc... and it works.

Comment: Which version of node are you running?

Comment: Sounds very similar to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40215393/chrome-54-doesnt-get-https-response-from-my-site-chrome-53-chromium-firefox/40216153). Turned out that the poster of that question was using `spdy` instead of `https`. There's also a content-negotiation issue: when a client sends `Accept:*/*`, it gets back a 404; when it sends `Accept:text/html`, it gets proper HTML.

Comment: @pgreen2 v5.9.0

Comment: @robertklep i use `spdy` indeed. Thanks for reference. I'll get back as soon as i'll try iy

Comment: Is it possible to upgrade node?  There has been some security release for node that could be causing problems with the latest version of chrome.  I agree with @stkvtflw that it feels like a problem with connection negotiation.  I would start with upgrading node to see if that does it.

Comment: @robertklep thank you a lot! That helped!

Comment: some time its happen we you login in chrome with multiple account mean you have add multiple account.just  logout from your account hope it will work well

Comment: @stkvtflw have you tried running it in a VM with a fresh install of Chrome?

Comment: @stkvtflw can you please take a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7334546/542592)